# Should I continue to use iVar and @property (nonatomic, retain) plus @synthesize under Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

Like a doop I'd been declaring Instant Variables (iVar) and then @property in the interface .h file for a while now.

```
@interface MainGameViewController : UIViewController {
     UserFactorsViewController *userFactorsViewController;
     UITableView *myTableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UserFactorsViewController *userFactorsViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

Under Automatic Reference Counting, should I just dispense with iVar and go all @property? Should I even have the word "retain" in property? What if I'm deploying for iOS 4.3, should I still use ARC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't feel like a doop, even though the compiler will add ivars for you if you don't include them, many people still declare them (many book authors as well) to make the code a little bit easier to read (easier to distinguish between ivar and property).

When creating a property now, Apple wants you to think in terms of Object Graphs, so do some research on "strong" and "weak" property attributes instead of retain and releases.

Also, iOS 4 is setup as a target for ARC so you should be ok. But I believe if you wanted to support iOS 3.0 you would have to manually manage retain and releases as before.

Comment: Thanks.  But what's the "correct" way to do it under ARC though? should I just have property and let synthesize take care of the rest? and just put property (nonatomic) for every STRONG object variable I have?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UserFactorsViewController *userFactorsViewController;`
`@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;`

Comment: Thank you so much Hans. Appreciate it.

Comment: This blog post might help understand ARC  http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/

Comment: If your run the edit>refactor>convert to ARC tool it will actually convert all your properties for you.

Comment: The correct way is to follow the standards, don't define ivars and don't do @synthesize. Use the Modern Objective C features.